# Empty function $f: \emptyset\to X$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I am new to the community. I am self-studying the real analysis from Analysis I by Terence Tao and I had a question related to function. I don't know the reason behind the statement.

A rather boring example of a function is the empty function f : ∅→
X from the empty set to a given set X. Since the empty set has no elements, we do
not need to specify what f does to any input. Nevertheless, just as the empty set is
a set, the empty function is a function, albeit not a particularly interesting one. **Note
that for each set X, there is only one function from ∅ to X, since Definition 3.3.8
asserts that all functions from ∅ to X are equal (why?).**

How can I tackle this and any formal proofs can be provided? Thank you.

Comment: It is because its graph is $\varnothing,$ as a subset of $\varnothing\times X=\varnothing.$

Comment: Does it mean that X is an empty set?

Comment: No, the argument holds for any codomain $X,$ not necessarily equal to *the* empty set.

Comment: That's vacuously true. Let f and g be any such functions. Now let x be an element of the empty set, therefore, f(x)=g(x). Since x was arbitrary we have that f=g by definition of equality of functions. I used that a false statement can imply  any other statement (that's a vacuous truth) in this particular case x is in the empty set which is a false statement.

Comment: The empty set can only be mapped to itself, that is why all such functions are the same.

Comment: @Abezhiko That is insufficient; one also needs the fact that for each set $X$ there is a unique embedding of $\emptyset$ into $X$.